# Meteor methods - stream/yield data from server

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, stream, generator

I'm writing a Meteor app which allows clients to execute terminal commands on the server at the click of a button.

I know how to do this with a single command:

```
//server
Meteor.methods({ exec : cmd => { ... } })

//client
Meteor.call('exec', cmd, (err, result) => {
    console.log(result)
})
```

But now I'm trying to implement a more complex protocol and don't quite know what the best way is. I want the client to kick off a series of commands, have the server run them and tell me, step by step, whether they succeeded or failed.

Obviously I could implement this with the above code by writing client-side code that runs `exec` with the first command, checks the result from the server, runs `exec` with the next command and so on.

The crux is that in my case the series of commands is always the same, so it would make much more sense to only do one `Meteor.call` on the client -- the server would know what commands to run. However I would also like to  have the results of the individual commands available on the client as they come in -- and this is what I can't do, because `Meteor.call` only returns once, of course.

What I'm looking for is a sort of stream or iterator through which I can send a number of messages to the client until everything is done. I've seen some outdated packages called `meteor-streams` and similar that might be able to do something like that, but I'm thinking there must be a smart way in Meteor itself to solve this. Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common solution is a `Notifications` collection. Create the collection with a schema: `for: ${userid}, msg: ${msg string}, type: ${err success etc}`. Create a Notifications publication, which publishes docs with the users `userid`.

You can then subscribe to the `Notifications` collection in some main template page on the client. Use `observeChanges` to look for changes to the collection and either console.log them, use JavaScript to display them on the page or simply install a package like `sAlerts` to handle them.

Inside the observe changes callback, a `seenNotification` method should be called which removes the notification from the db, so it is not shown again.

I'll post code snippets a bit later.

Comment: I was thinking something like this would be the way to go. Thanks for the detailed explanation! I'll accept unless someone comes up with an approach that doesn't involve a database at all -- which I doubt.